# Problem showing file info with Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of files made by my PHP code

```
if ($handle = opendir($director))   
{
    $path="images/files/nou/";
    if(Files::is_empty_dir($director))
        {
            echo "<p>There are no script available.</p>";
        }
    else
        {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
   {
         if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
        $size=Files::getSize($director."/".$file);
        $exts=Files::getExtension($file);
                $filex = str_replace(".".$exts,"",$file);
            if(strlen($filex)>10)
                {
                    $filex=substr($filex,0,6);
                }
                echo "<div class='file' title='".$file."'>".$filex."</div>";
```

There are functions defined in my own class Files.
Good. I want that on mouseover to show file information with this code

```
function getInfo($file)
        {
            $info="<div class='info_public'><table border=0 cellpadding=2><tr>";
            $info.="<td>File : </td><td>".$file."</td></tr>";
            $info.="<tr><td>Extension : </td><td>".Files::getExtension($file)."</td></tr>";
            $info.="<tr><td>Size : </td><td>".Files::getSize($file)."</td></tr>";

            return $info;
        }
```

I want to show info dynamically with JQuery. I wrote this

```
$(".file").mouseover(function()
    {
        data=$(this).attr("title");
        alert(data);
    });
```

It alerts always first filename not what I crossed with mouse. But if I disable mouseover JQuery function, the title appears correctly for each file in part. If I use mouseover function, the selected value from title doesn't appear correctly, it shows first filename in alert no matter what file I crossed with mouse.

I called the alert function to see results before implementing $.ajax function to avoid bad responses.
What's the problem in my script ?

Thank you

Comment: use console.log() instead of alert bro,

Comment: what is sample of html generated by your php ?

Comment: I posted <div title='$file'> and for each file will appear their filename in title of div element. So I want to alert the correct filename no first like as my above situation

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery code works, so check something else, may be you need to onload() that script ?
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hJyRm/

Comment: have you a TeamViewer software that I could show you my problem ? That mouseover function has beem already included in $(function() body function.